# Conversion tracking in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, google-analytics

I'm trying to figure out how to get Expresso:Store to add the necessary Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking code after checkout.

Although the docs say you simply have to enable the Conversion Tracking within the Expresso:Store control panel this doesn't seem to do anything.

The standard Google Analytics code is there but no specific product data is tracked.

Is this something that *should* be happening or am I expecting more than it's meant to do. The docs aren't very detailed.

Comment: Any idea/example of this on the thank you page?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it's necessary to output the order details on the "thank you" page in order for it to output the necessary GA product tracking code.